# Why do most programming languages have special keyword or syntax for declaring functions?

Tags: language-design, scala, syntax, functions, grammar

Most programming languages (both dynamically and statically typed languages) have special keyword and/or syntax that looks much different than declaring variables for declaring functions. I see functions as just as declaring another named entity:

For example in Python:

```
x = 2
y = addOne(x)
def addOne(number): 
  return number + 1
```

Why not:

```
x = 2
y = addOne(x)
addOne = (number) => 
  return number + 1
```

Similarly, in a language like Java:

```
int x = 2;
int y = addOne(x);

int addOne(int x) {
  return x + 1;
}
```

Why not:

```
int x = 2;
int y = addOne(x);
(int => int) addOne = (x) => {
  return x + 1;
}
```

This syntax seems more natural way of declaring something (be it a function or a variable) and one less keyword like `def` or `function` in some languages. And, IMO, it is more consistent (I look in the same place to understand the type of a variable or function) and probably makes the parser/grammar a little bit simpler to write.

I know very few languages uses this idea (CoffeeScript, Haskell) but most common languages have special syntax for functions (Java, C++, Python, JavaScript, C#, PHP, Ruby).

Even in Scala, which supports both ways (and has type inference), it more common to write:

```
def addOne(x: Int) = x + 1
```

Rather than:

```
val addOne = (x: Int) => x + 1
```

IMO, atleast in Scala, this is probably the most easily understandable version but this idiom is seldom followed:

```
val x: Int = 1
val y: Int = addOne(x)
val addOne: (Int => Int) = x => x + 1
```

I am working on my own toy language and I am wondering if there are any pitfalls if I design my language in such a way and if there are any historical or technical reasons this pattern is not widely followed?

Comment: I know in the case of scala, `def` is not equivalent to `val` with a function. It does some things when it compiles that allow things like overloading and generic type arguments, which are not usable in anonymous functions assigned to a value. That being said, several functional languages *do* use the same syntax for defining values and functions. Take Haskell, where it's equally valid to say `x = 10` as a top-level value, and `addOne x = x + 1` as a top-level function.

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [How do programming languages define functions?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/210558/how-do-programming-languages-define-functions)

Comment: The duplicate use of `=>` means it's harder for your parser to give good error messages and recover, especially in partial parsing scenarios (intellisense when a statement is incomplete).

Comment: The reason is likely historical. Whoever did it first did it that way, and everyone else copied. But I doubt we can know for sure.

Comment: Just FYI: Your second "why not" example is syntactically identical to CoffeeScript.

Comment: @KChaloux: Even in functional codebases which does not have much inheritance etc (e.g. a math or statistics library) I have seen `def` being used over `val` in Scala even though the latter seems more natural.

Comment: @greyfade: I do admit, I like the CoffeeScript/Haskell style more :)

Comment: since you mention Scala, consider also taking a look at [Is duplicate syntax for defining named functions a bad language design decision?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/245627/is-duplicate-syntax-for-defining-named-functions-a-bad-language-design-decision)

Comment: http://youtu.be/gRdfX7ut8gw ;)

Comment: I think it is because a function or method _simply is not just another named entity_. In functional languages, they are (you can pass them around etc.) but in other languages (like Java) a function or method is something entirely different from a simple variable and cannot be treated as such (I admit Java 8 kind of weakens this statement), so it makes sense to define functions/methods differently, since they _behave_ differently.

Comment: @wrick as @11684 points out, `def` is more common because it's the proper way to define methods in Scala, which are **not** the same as functions. Part of this has to do with the fact that Scala has to be interoperable with Java and the JVM.

Comment: Note that in Python, you can in some cases use `addOne = lambda number: number + 1`. (Even better, in Ruby you are substantially less limited regarding what you can put in the body of the lambda expression.)

Comment: A datapoint: Standard ML treats your form as the "real way to define a function," and the special function declaration syntax is a derived form of the "real way." In fact, the SML/NJ compiler actually transforms `fun f x = ...` in to `val f = fn x => ...` before typechecking. For humans, though, the former is much more concise and easier to read.

Comment: I disagree that your proposal is a more natural way of declaring functions. I really dislike Coffeescript's syntax and part of that is to do with its function declaration syntax. The fact is, if it ain't broke don't fix it. Writing 'def' or 'function' is not a big deal and is way more obvious an a glance compared to some fancy Perl-like symbols which with unthinking or tired eyes could easily be mistaken for something else. On a completely personal note I also think your suggested syntax in the examples look much uglier than the current syntax.

Comment: I run into three classes of "issues" implementing a language, (1) parser issues / grammar ambiguities and (2) concepts which involve a lot of work, even though they are simple to parse (generics for example) and (3) personal preference: stuff that works, but people don't like it or can't read it. Your proposal is probably a simple one to implement, so why not try it? Personally, I treat functions as types. Visually I want functions to stand out like type definitions, and not appear to be assignment expressions. The point of doing your own language is to do it your own way, though. :)

Comment: Scheme has what you describe: `(define n 123)` declares variable `n`, and `(define add1 (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))` defines a procedure `add1`. Although you often end up using the shorthand, `(define (add1 x) (+ x 1))`. And yes, I also find it perfectly natural to use the same way to define both types of objects.

Comment: This really should be a blog post, not a question.

Comment: @Roy: Funnily, I dislike Javascript's way and like CoffeeScript's function style. For me declaring a variable and declaring a function is same i.e. I am giving a name to some piece of code (be it a constant or a function).

Comment: The question "why do you need a syntax for nominal functions if you have lambdas and variables?" is reasonable, but why stop there?  Why have a syntax for events? An event is just a rule for combining functions. Why have properties? Just a pair of functions. Why have *strings*? Strings are just functions that take integers and return characters. Why have *integers*? Just use Church Numerals as your integers. In fact, *why have anything at all except the S and K combinator*?

Comment: Make sure to look at how Go does function declarations.

Comment: How is '=>' not a "special keyword *or syntax* for declaring a function"?

Comment: I don't know about you, but to me `(int => int) addOne = (x) => {` is a lot more "special" and "complex" than `int addOne(int) {`...

Comment: [Von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) started it.

Comment: FWIW, JavaScript can declare functions with the variable assignment operator: `var f = function(...) { ... };`.

Comment: Bogdan Alexandru said it. `(int => int) addOne = (x) => ` says nothing of what is going on unless one is deep in the rabbit hole already.

Comment: @Jakob: `int addOne(int x)` conveys the same amount as `(int => int) addOne` isn't it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think the reason is that most popular languages either come from or were influenced by the C family of languages as opposed to functional languages and their root, the lambda calculus.

And in these languages, functions are *not* just another value:

- In C++, C# and Java, you can overload functions: you can have two functions with the same name, but different signature.
- In C, C++, C# and Java, you can have values that represent functions, but function pointers, functors, delegates and functional interfaces all are distinct from functions themselves. Part of the reason is that most of those are not actually just functions, they are a function together with some (mutable) state.
- Variables are mutable by default (you have to use `const`, `readonly` or `final` to forbid mutation), but functions can't be reassigned.
- From a more technical perspective, code (which is composed of functions) and data are separate. They typically occupy different parts of memory, and they are accessed differently: code is loaded once and then only executed (but not read or written), whereas data is often constantly allocated and deallocated and is being written and read, but never executed.

  And since C was meant to be "close to the metal", it makes sense to mirror this distinction in the syntax of the language too.
- The "function is just a value" approach that forms the basis of functional programming has gained traction in the common languages only relatively recently, as evidenced by the late introduction of lambdas in C++, C# and Java (2011, 2007, 2014).

Comment: C# had anonymous functions -- which are just lambdas without type inference and a clunky syntax -- since 2005.

Comment: "From a more technical perspective, code (which is composed of functions) and data are separate" - some languages, most well knowingly LISPs don't make that separation and don't really treat code and data too differently. (LISPs are the most well known example, but there are a bunch of other languages like REBOL that do this)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I was talking about compiled code in memory, not about the language level.

Comment: C has function pointers which, at least slightly, can be regarded as just another value.  A dangerous value to mess with to be sure, but stranger things have happened.

Comment: @PatrickHughes Yeah, I mention them in my second point. But function pointers are quite different from functions.

Answer (score 60):

It's because it's important for **humans** to recognize that functions are not just "another named entity". Sometimes it makes sense to manipulate them as such, but they are still able to be recognized at a glance.

It doesn't really matter what the computer thinks about the syntax, as an incomprehensible blob of characters is fine for a machine to interpret, but that would be nigh-impossible for humans to understand and maintain.

It really is the same reason as why we have while and for loops, switch and if else, etc, even though all of them ultimately boil down to a a compare and jump instruction. The reason is because it's there for the benefit of the humans maintaining and understanding the code.

Having your functions as "another named entity" the way you are proposing will make your code harder to see, and thus harder to understand.

Comment: I disagree that treating functions as named entities *necessarily* makes code harder to understand. That almost certainly true for any code that follows a procedural paradigm, but it may not be true for code that follows a functional paradigm.

Comment: "It really is the same reason as why we have while and for loops, switch and if else, etc, **even though all of them ultimately boil down to a a compare and jump instruction.**" +1 to that. If all programmers were comfortable with machine language, we wouldn't need all these fancy programming languages (high or low level). But the truth is: everybody has a different comfort level as to how close to the machine they want to write their code. Once you find your level, you just have to stick with the syntax given to you (or write your own language specs and compiler if you're really bothered).

Comment: +1. A more concise version might be "Why do all natural languages distinguish nouns from verbs?"

Comment: "an incomprehensible blob of characters is fine for a machine to interpret, but that would be nigh-impossible for humans to understand and maintain" What a rash qualification for such a modest syntactical change as proposed in the question. One quickly adapts to syntax. This proposal is a much less radical departure from convention than the OO method call syntax _object.method(args)_ was in its time, yet the latter has not proved to be nigh-impossible for humans to understand and maintain. Despite the fact that in most OO languages methods should not be thought of as stored in class instances.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen. Your comment is true and make sense, but some confusion is provoked by the way the original post is redacted. There are actually 2 questions: (i) _Why is it this way?_ and (ii) _Why not this way instead?_. The answer by `whatsisname` was more addressing the first point (and alerting on some danger of removing these failsafe), while your comment is more related to the second part of the question. It is possible indeed to change this syntax (and as you described, it has been done many times already...) but it won't suit everybody (as _oop_ doesn't suit everybody either.

Comment: **re Hoki**: "why we have while and for loops" – I disagree with that one. The reason most languages need loops etc. as built-in syntax is that they aren't flexible enough to define this kind of thing within the language (at least not efficiently). In Common Lisp, loops and decision functions are macros like you could also define yourself. In Haskell, which properly keeps track of side-effects etc. rather then having a fuzzy notion of "execution environment" and mutable state, loops are [simply library functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#g:4)!

Answer (score 11):

You might be interested to learn that, way back in prehistoric times, a language called ALGOL 68 used a syntax close to what you propose.
Recognising that function identifiers are bound to values just like other identifiers are, you could in that language declare a function (constant) using the syntax

> *function-type* *name* = (*parameter-list*) *result-type* : *body* ;

Concretely your example would read

```
PROC (INT)INT add one = (INT n) INT: n+1;
```

Recognising the redundancy in that the initial type can be read off from the RHS of the declaration, and being a function type always starts with `PROC`, this could (and usually would) be contracted to

```
PROC add one = (INT n) INT: n+1;
```

but note that the `=` still comes *before* the parameter list. Also note that if you wanted a function *variable* (to which another value of the same function type could later be assigned), the `=` should be replaced by `:=`, giving either one of

```
PROC (INT)INT func var := (INT n) INT: n+1;
PROC func var := (INT n) INT: n+1;
```

However in this case both forms are in fact abbreviations; since the identifier `func var` designates a reference to a locally generated function, the fully expanded form would be

```
REF PROC (INT)INT func var = LOC PROC (INT)INT := (INT n) INT: n+1;
```

This particular syntactic form is easy to get used to, but it clearly did not have a large following in other programming languages. Even functional programming languages like Haskell prefer the style `f n = n+1` with `=` *following* the parameter list. I guess the reason is mainly psychological; after all even mathematicians don't often prefer, as I do, *f* = *n* ⟼ *n* + 1 over *f*(*n*) = *n* + 1.

By the way, the above discussion does highlight one important difference between variables and functions: function definitions usually bind a name to one specific function value, that cannot be later changed, whereas variable definitions usually introduce an identifier with an *initial* value, but one that can change later. (It is not an absolute rule; function variables and non-function constants do occur in most languages.) Moreover, in compiled languages the value bound in a function definition is usually a compile-time constant, so that calls to the function can be compiled using a fixed address in the code. In C/C++ this is even a requirement; the equivalent of the ALGOL 68

```
PROC (REAL) REAL f = IF mood=sunny THEN sin ELSE cos FI;
```

cannot be written in C++ without introducing a function pointer. This kind of specific limitations justify using a different syntax for function definitions. But they depend on the language semantics, and the justification does not apply to all languages.

Comment: "Mathematicians don't prefer _f_ = _n_ ⟼ _n_ + 1 over _f_ (_n_) = _n_ + 1" ... Not to mention physicists, who like to write only _f_ = _n_ + 1 ...

Comment: @leftaroundabout that's because ⟼ is a pain to write. Honestly.

Answer (score 8):

You mentioned Java and Scala as examples. However, you overlooked an important fact: those aren't functions, those are methods. Methods and functions are *fundamentally* different. Functions are objects, methods belong to objects.

In Scala, which has both functions and methods, there are the following differences between methods and functions:

- methods can be generic, functions can't
- methods can have no, one or many parameter lists, functions always have exactly one parameter list
- methods can have an implicit parameter list, functions can't
- methods can have optional parameters with default arguments, functions can't
- methods can have repeated parameters, functions can't
- methods can have by-name parameters, functions can't
- methods can be called with named arguments, functions can't
- functions are objects, methods aren't

So, your proposed replacement simply doesn't work, at least for those cases.

Comment: "Functions are objects, methods belong to objects." Is that supposed to apply to all languages (like C++)?

Comment: "methods can have by-name parameters, functions can't" - this isn't a fundamental difference between methods and functions, it's just a quirk of Scala. Same with most (all?) of the others.

Comment: Methods are fundamentally just a special kind of functions. -1. Note that Java (and by extension Scala) doesn't have any other kind of functions. It's "functions" are objects with one method (in general functions may not be objects or even first class values; whether they are depends on the language).

Comment: @JanHudec: Semantically, Java has both functions and methods; it uses the terminology "static methods" when referring to functions, but such terminology doesn't erase the semantic distinction.

Answer (score 3):

The reasons that I can think of are:

- It is easier for the compiler to know what we declaring.
- It's important for us to know (in a trivial way) whether this is a function or a variable. Functions are usually black boxes and we don't care about their internal implementation. I dislike type inference on return types in Scala, because I believe that it's easier to use a function that has a return type: it is often the only documentation provided.
- And the most important one is the *following the crowd* strategy that is used in designing programming languages. C++ was created to steal C programmers, and Java was designed in a way that doesn't scare C++ programmers, and C# to attract Java programmers. Even C#, which I think is a very modern language with an amazing team behind it, copied some mistakes from Java or even from C.

Comment: "…and C# to attract Java programmers" — this is questionable, C# is much more similar to C++ than is Java. and sometimes it looks like it was made intentionally incompatible with Java (no wildcards, no inner classes, no return type covariance…)

Comment: @SargeBorsch I don't think it was intentionally made incompatible with Java, I'm pretty sure the C# team simply tried to do it right, or do it better, however you want to look at it. Microsoft already wrote their own Java & JVM and got sued. So C# team was likely _very_ motivated to eclipse Java. It is surely incompatible, and better for it. Java started out with some basic limitations and I'm glad that C# team chose, for example, to do generics differently (visible in the type system and not just sugar).

Answer (score 2):

Turning the question around, if one isn't interested in trying to edit source code on a machine which is extremely RAM-constrained, or minimize the time to read it off a floppy disk, what's wrong with using keywords?

Certainly it's nicer to read `x=y+z` than `store the value of y plus z into x`, but that doesn't mean that punctuation characters are inherently "better" than keywords.  If variables `i`, `j`, and `k` are `Integer`, and `x` is `Real`, consider the following lines in Pascal:

```
k := i div j;
x := i/j;
```

The first line will perform a truncating integer division, while the second will perform a real-number division.  The distinction can be made nicely because Pascal uses `div` as its truncating-integer-division operator, rather than trying to use a punctuation mark which already has another purpose (real-number division).

While there are a few contexts in which it can be helpful to make a function definition concise (e.g. a lambda which is used as part of another expression), functions are generally supposed to stand out and be easily visually recognizable as functions.  While it might be possible to make the distinction much more subtle and use nothing but punctuation characters, what would be the point?  Saying `Function Foo(A,B: Integer; C: Real): String` makes it clear what the function's name is, what parameters it expects, and what it returns.  Maybe one could shorten it by six or seven characters by replacing `Function` with some punctuation characters, but what would be gained?

Another thing to note is that there is an most frameworks a fundamental difference between a declaration which will always associate a name with either a particular method or a particular virtual binding, and one which creates a variable which initially identifies a particular method or binding, but could be changed *at runtime* to identify another.  Since these are very semantically very different concepts in most procedural frameworks, it makes sense that they should have different syntax.

Comment: I don't think this question is about conciseness. Especially since for example `void f() {}` is actually shorter than the lambda equivalent in C++ (`auto f = [](){};`), C# (`Action f = () => {};`) and Java (`Runnable f = () -> {};`). The conciseness of lambdas comes from type inference and omitting `return`, but I don't think that's related to what this questions asks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the reason might be, that those languages are not functional enough, so to say. In other words, you rather seldomly define functions. Thus, the use of an extra key word is acceptable.

In languages of the ML or Miranda heritage, OTOH, you define functions most of the time. Look at some Haskell code, for instance. It's literally mostly a sequence of function definitions, many of those have local functions and local functions of those local functions. Hence, a **fun** keyword in Haskell would be a mistake as great as requiring an assingment statement in an imperative language to start with **assign**. Cause assignment is probably by far the single most frequent statement.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I see no fatal flaw in your idea; you may find that it's trickier than you expected to express certain things using your new syntax, and/or you may find that you need to revise it (adding various special cases and other features, etc), but I doubt you'll find yourself needing to abandon the idea entirely.

The syntax you've proposed looks more or less like a variant of some of the notation styles sometimes used to express functions or types of functions in mathematics. This means that, like all grammars, it will probably appeal more to some programmers than others. (As a mathematician, I happen to like it.)

However, you should note that in most languages, the `def`-style syntax (i.e. the traditional syntax) *does* behave differently from a standard variable assignment.

- In the `C` and `C++` family, functions aren't generally treated as "objects", i.e. chunks of typed data to be copied and put on the stack and whatnot. (Yes, you can have function pointers, but those still point at executable code, not at "data" in the typical sense.)
- In most OO languages, there's special handling for methods (i.e. member functions); that is, they're not just functions declared inside the scope of a class definition. The most important difference is that the object on which the method is being called is typically passed as an implicit first parameter to the method. Python makes this explicit with `self` (which, by the way, is not actually a keyword; you could make any valid identifier the first argument of a method).

You need to consider whether your new syntax accurately (and hopefully intuitively) represents what the compiler or interpreter is actually doing. It may help to read up on, say, the difference between lambdas and methods in Ruby; this will give you an idea of how your functions-are-just-data paradigm differs from the typical OO/procedural paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

For some languages functions are not values. In such a language to say that

```
val f = << i : int  ... >> ;
```

is a function definition, whereas

```
val a = 1 ;
```

declares a constant, is confusing because you are using one syntax to mean two things.

Other languages, such as ML, Haskell, and Scheme treat functions as 1st class values, but provide the user with a special syntax for declaring function valued constants.*  They are applying the rule that "usage shortens form". I.e. if a construct is both common and verbose, you should give the user a shorthand.  It is inelegant to give the user two different syntaxes that mean exactly the same thing; sometimes elegance should be sacrificed to utility.

If, in your language, functions are 1st class, then why not try to find a syntax that is concise enough that you won't be tempted to find a syntactic sugar?

-- Edit --

Another issue no one has brought up (yet) is recursion.  If you allow

```
{ 
    val f = << i : int ... g(i-1) ... >> ;
    val g = << j : int ... f(i-1) ... >> ;
    f(x)
}
```

and you allow

```
{
    val a = 42 ;
    val b = a + 1 ;
    a
} ,
```

does it follow that you should allow

```
{
    val a = b + 1 ; 
    val b = a - 1 ;
    a
} ?
```

In a lazy language (like Haskell), there is no issue here. In an language with essentially no static checks (like LISP), there is no issue here. But in a statically-checked eager language, you have to be careful about how the rules of static checking are defined, if you want to allow the first two and forbid the last.

-- End of Edit --

*It might be argued that Haskell does not belong in this list. It provides two ways to declare a function, but both are, in a sense, generalizations of the syntax for declaring constants of other types

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful on dynamic languages where the type is not that important, but it's not that readable in static typed languages where always you want to know the type of your variable. Also, in object-oriented languages it's pretty important to know the type of your variable, in order to know what operations it supports.

In your case, a function with 4 variables would be:

```
(int, long, double, String => int) addOne = (x, y, z, s) => {
  return x + 1;
}
```

When I look at the function header and see (x, y, z, s) but I do not know the types of these variables. If I want to know the type of `z` which is the third parameter, I'll have to look at the beginning of the function and start counting 1, 2, 3 and then to see that the type is `double`. In the former way I look directly and see `double z`.

Comment: Of course there's that wonderful thing called type inference, which allows you to write something like `var addOne = (int x, long y, double z, String s) => { x + 1 }` in a non-moronic statically typed language of your choice (examples: C#, C++, Scala). Even the otherwise very limited local type inference used by C# is completely sufficient for this. So this answer is merely criticizing a specific syntax that's dubious in the first place, and not actually used anywhere (although Haskell's syntax has a very similar problem).

Comment: @amon His answer may be criticizing the syntax, but it also points out that the purposed syntax in the question may not be "natural" to everyone.

Comment: @amon The usefulness of type inference is a not a wonderful thing for everyone. If you read code more often that you write code, then type inference is bad because you have to infer in your head the type when reading the code; and is way more faster to read the type than to actually think about what type is used.

Comment: The criticism seems valid to me. For Java, the OP seems to think [input, output, name, input] is a simpler / clearer function def than simply [output, name, input]? As @m3th0dman states, with longer signatures, the OP's 'cleaner' approach becomes very long-winded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple reason to have such a distinction in most languages: there is a need to distinguish **evaluation** and **declaration**. Your example is good: why not like variables? Well, variables expressions are immediately evaluated.

Haskell has a special model where there is no distinction between evaluation and declaration, which is why there is no need for a special keyword.

Comment: But some syntax for lambda functions also solves this, so why not use that?

Answer (score 0):

Functions are declared differently from literals, objects, etc. in most languages because they are used differently, debugged differently, and pose different potential sources of error.

If a dynamic object reference or a mutable object is passed to a function, the function can change the value of the object as it runs.  This kind of side effect can make it difficult to follow what a function will do if it is nested within a complex expression, and this is a common problem in languages like C++ and Java.

Consider debugging some sort of kernel module in Java, where every object has a toString() operation.  While it may be expected that the toString() method should restore the object, it may need to disassemble and reassemble the object in order to translate its value to a String object.  If you're trying to debug the methods that toString() will be calling (in a hook-and-template scenario) to do its work, and accidentally highlight the object in the variables window of most IDE's, it can crash the debugger.  This is because the IDE will try to toString() the object which calls the very code you're in the process of debugging.  No primitive value ever does crap like this because the semantic meaning of primitive values is defined by the language, not the programmer.